# Create index on composite columns or each combination uniquely

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

In my scenario, I have following columns.

a, b, c, d, e, f

```
-> f is updated time stamp
-> b has cardinality of two distinct elements.
-> c and d columns have maximum distinct elements 10.
-> = queries on columns a, b and like queries on columns c, d and e
```

My Query combinations look like below.

```
a b ORDER BY DESC f
a b c ORDER BY DESC f
a b d ORDER BY DESC f
a b e ORDER BY DESC f
```

I would like to know, what are the feasible options to create index.

a. Can I create an index on (a, b, c, d, e) or (a, b, c, d, e, f) together?

b. Is adding timestamp column f to the index helps?

c. Is the order of columns mentioned in the index improve the performance?

**Sample Queries**

```
SELECT * FROM SampleTable T WHERE T.a = 123 and T.b='y' ORDER BY DESC T.f
SELECT * FROM SampleTable T WHERE T.a = 123 and T.b='y' and T.c Like '' ORDER BY DESC T.f
SELECT * FROM SampleTable T WHERE T.a = 123 and T.b='y' and T.d Like '' ORDER BY DESC T.f
SELECT * FROM SampleTable T WHERE T.a = 123 and T.b='y' and T.e Like '' ORDER BY DESC T.f
```

Comment: You need to at least show us the actual queries being considered here.

Comment: Updated with sample queries

Comment: You should add composite indices for the queries you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a. Can I create an index on (a, b, c, d, e) or (a, b, c, d, e, f) together?

`INDEX(a, b, c, d, e, f)` will handle cases where `(a, b, c, d, e)` is needed.  So, do only the longer one.  BUT -- this will not *fully* handle any of your sample `SELECTs`.

> b. Is adding timestamp column f to the index helps?

Yes.  For example `WHERE T.a = 123 and T.b='y' ORDER BY DESC T.f` will like `INDEX(a,b)`, but like `(a,b,f)` even more.  BUT not `(a,b,c,f)` is no better than `(a,b)`.  Only the leftmost are used; `c` is in the way.

> c. Is the order of columns mentioned in the index improve the performance?

It depends.  `WHERE T.a = 123 and T.b='y'` is equally happy with `INDEX(a,b)` as `(b,a)`.  BUT that assumes both tests are `=`.  (Also, "cardinality" does not matter.)

> AND c Like ''

That is identical to `AND c = ''`.  BUT `AND c LIKE 'x%' works like a "range" and` AND c LIKE '%x'`cannot use an index for`c`.

To handle all 4 of your sample queries optimally, you would need 4 indexes.  However, the following one index may be a reasonable compromise:

```
INDEX(a,b,f)
```

Read this; it says all that, plus more:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 1):

Situation 1：This table have and only have the following columns, `a, b, c, d, e, f`

Situation 2: This table have more columns

For situation 1, I think you don't need to create index on (a, b, c, d, e) or (a, b, c, d, e, f), because:

1. the cardinality of b and c is not too large, so that it's almost same as full scan. If using index on (a, b, c, d, e) or (a, b, c, d, e, f), it still need to return table.
2. because of leftmost prefix of the index, both (a, b, c, d, e) and (a, b, c, d, e, f) couldn't statisfy all query.

For situation 2, I don't think you need to create those 2 indexes, either:

1. Leftmost prefix again
2. I notice sql will get all columns back. Therefore, for both indexes, mysql need to return table and get all needed columns data.

Then what index you should add?
I think that should depend your bussiness.

---

If this table wouldn't be updated too offen, and will do a lot queries, I think you could add serveral different indexes to improve query performance.

```
index on (a b f)
index on (a b c f)
index on (a b d f)
index on (a b e f)
```

---

If both query and update existed, too many index will be expansive. We need to consider carefully. I notice you have list the cardinality of b, c and d, all three column have a small cardinality of distinct elements. Maybe e have larger cardinality of distinct elements. With that said, add index on (a, b, c) or (a, b, d) is nearly the same as using indexes and then filter according the return table data. (a, b, e) may be more efficent.

```
index on (a, b, e)
```

---

Considering sort by f, I'm not sure what the cardinality is. If final query result is not too large, msyql will use mysql sort buffer. Therefore add f is not nessesary.
If result is too large, maybe you could consider:

```
index on (a, b, f).
```

when query condition is like `a = xxx and b = yyy order by f`, mysql will not need to sort result. It just return table and read all columns, then return to client.

when query condition is like `a = xxx and b = yyy and c like 'zzz' order by f` or `a = xxx and b = yyy and d like 'zzz' order by f`, or `a = xxx and b = yyy and e like 'zzz' order by f`. Because a and b is equal condition, and the index is like (a, b, f), with that said, the result is sorted by f when condition is `a = xxx and b = yyy`. Actually, mysql will retrive data from innodb one by one, the detail step is as following:

1. retrieve first primary id by index (a, b, f) according to condition `a = xxx and b = yyy`
2. return table and get all needed columns from cluster index
3. check other query condition, like `d like 'zzz'`. If match, put into result set. If not match, just disguard.
4. repeat step 1, 2 and 3, till no match data found.
5. return result to client

> Notes: the workflow only work when the query conditions must contain a and b, and related conditions must be equal condition, like "a = xxx and b = yyy". Otherwise, mysql will execute in other workflow and will use file or sort_buffer to sort result.

Anyway, all of these analysis above are in theory. The best way is still to do some test on your environment. No matter how efficent you created indexes are, it could become worse when business changes.

Comment: When the `INDEX` contains _all_ the columns mentioned in the `SELECT`, it is called "covering".  This, alone, provides an extra performance boost.  So, in situation 1, all the selects would benefit from `INDEX(a, b, c, d, e, f)`.